# How to debug AS400 RGPILE program when there DBGVIEW is set to *none

Tags: debugging, ibm-midrange, rpgle

My company has recently modified the way RPGILE and CL programs are compiled and delivered to our clients.  All programs are set to DBGVIEW *NONE and no source is set to any client system.  When you try to debug a program all you see is Program X cannot be debugged.

Is there any way we can debug a program set like this?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no.

Long answer, for currently supported release of IBM i OS, use the
**Debug encryption key (DBGENCKEY)**  and **DBGVIEW(*LIST)**

parameters of the compile commands to include an encrypted copy of the source with the program objects.

Optionally, if you use DBGVIEW(*SOURCE) along with RDi for debugging, I believe you can point RDi to the source on your PC.

Comment: I had thought this as well. but when I do the debug I still can see the source without using the encryption key.

Comment: if you're testing on the same box you compiled on, the system will find the source member rather than pull the source from the object.  Rename the source member after you compile so it can't find it.